# How to change instance of class field for unit test in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, dependency-injection

I would like to create a unit test of this class but I would like the instance of the countryRepository: CountryRepository to be a mock in the case of the test.

I could create an alternative constructor to pass another instance but it doesn't seem like a great solution

How could I do?

```
class CountryListModel {

    var countryRepository:CountryRepository = CountryRepositoryImp()

}
```

Comment: This code doesn't look like Java to me. And yes, this is why you want dependency injection.

Comment: I'm sorry, its kotlin... i write java for habit.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it inside the constructor with default value:

```
class CountryListModel(val countryRepository:CountryRepository = CountryRepositoryImp())
```